# What is the control used as a popup window in this widget?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Can someone help me identify the control used as the contact options popup (Call, Email SMS) in this screenshot?
http://64.19.142.12/i.techrepublic.com.com/gallery/452166-480-800.jpg

This is a screenshot of the PictureDial widget, which can be downloaded here:
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jasoncalhoun.android.picturedialwidget

The Android docs indicate that widgets support only these controls:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

The PictureDial popup window does not seem to match any of the above. So what is it and how is it created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the quick contact badge

Comment: Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/QuickContactBadge.html